# cannot enter text into the text fields on a form when using IE

Tags: custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

When on the site  and using IE, it is not possible to type in the text fields, the two textareas work ok. Please can someone go to this site and look at 'view source' and tell me why it is not possible to type in the text fields while using IE? I am really struggling to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text is there, just hidden. I proved this by writing something in there then shift + left arrow to highlight whatever (if anything was in there) and copying it out. It worked.

In terms of the issue it seems to be linked to the padding size. 16px with a 28px max-height. 16x2(top and bottom) being 32 and whatnot doesn't leave much room for the font ;). Now as to why Chrome is smart enough to take your 32px and 0 height element and make it show text, I don't know, supposedly its just better. Cue all the clever people now that will explain the intricacies of how IE and Chrome deal with these issues (or will link some already enlightening posts). By the by, it doesn't work in Firefox either without a fix.

Anyways the CSS below is the issue. Lines 3773 and 675 of your style.css. Changing the padding to something like 5px would make it 10px + 18px font size which is right on the 28px max-height. Oh and I don't know anything about WP so have no idea why or how or when or who or whatever the CSS file is generated by, but assume you can just modify it for now to get it working.

```
input, select, textarea {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    max-height: 28px;
}
```